# Error connecting to remote mysql through google cloud

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform

After I run a command regarding the database, I get this:

```
{ SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT ip:5432
    at connection.connect.err (/Users/me/Documents/PetHotel/backend-sql/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:128:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (/Users/me/Documents/PetHotel/backend-sql/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:140:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (/Users/me/Documents/PetHotel/backend-sql/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:71:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:72:19)
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
  parent:
   { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ip:5432
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1121:14)
     errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: 'ip',
     port: 5432 },
  original:
   { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ip:5432
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1121:14)
     errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: 'ip',
     port: 5432 } }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app-backend@ db:reset:development: `cross-env MIGRATION_ENV=development node ./migrations/reset`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app-backend@ db:reset:development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Is it something regarding google I wonder? I do have set 0.0.0.0/0 as authorised ip

Comment: You are showing an error with no information on how Cloud SQL is configured. Your code is using port 5432 where MySQL normally uses port 3306. Once you are able to connect correctly, redesign your app to use Cloud SQL Proxy instead. Allowing `0.0.0.0` through the firewall is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, it seems your app is not able to connect to CloudSQL instance possibly due to network restriction.
Opening instance to `0.0.0.0/0` is not a good idea.

Google suggest different ways yo connect to CloudSQL Instance [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app). One particular method is [sql-proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy).

Hope these guides helps you to establish connection between your app and cloudsql.

Comment: Thanks I will try, but if it doesn't work having 0.0.0.0/0 open, should it be something else?

Comment: The error suggest the timeout which means application is not able to reach to CloudSQL. I would suggest to try google recommended way to connect app with DB.
Also, to test connection, it might be easy to use "netcat" or "telnet" like tool